# Directive = or =attr not bi-directional

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope
>   property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value
>   of the attr attribute. ... Any changes to parentModel will be
>   reflected in localModel and any changes in localModel will reflect in
>   parentModel.

This is from Angular docs, and I have read a few post that say you DON'T get bi-directional binding when creating isolated scopes with directives. I am finding it difficult to understand. I want to create a widget, passing in state but I also want to be able to bind that state to other directives in the parent scope.

From my experiments you can't make a change to scope in the directive and pick up the change in it's parent controller/ other directive. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no an isolate scope (e.g. you've added a scope: {} to your directive) in angular is just that, an individual scope that is not linked in the prototypal inheritance chain. This means that by default and changes you make to the scope in the directive will not be reflected back into the scope of parent elements to this directive.

The '=' locals type in the scope creation sets up up a visible binding to the parent scope. Then changes to the isolated scope variable will be reflected back. Make sure your changes are being recognized by the locals scope in your directive or nothing will propagate up (e.g. try watching/$watch the locals variable to ensure a change is occurring in the directive, if not you may need to $apply depending on how you've bound within your directive).